# Mirror API - Share contact appears in myglass but not on device

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

This web app based share contact appears in myglass, but this same contact does not show up on device, when selecting share for an image.

The web app is also subscribed to the timeline

Comment: Can you share some more detail about this contact? Is it one you inserted? If so, what's the JSON representation? There are many reasons a contact may not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed some sync issues with contacts since the change to them a couple of weeks ago. What has worked for me was plugging Glass in while it is able to connect to WiFi, which seems to force it to do the full round of syncing. Could be coincidence, however.